# Convert to image from api response in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, base64

I built a Rest service to storage different types of images. When I tray to retrieve an image from service a get next response:

```
�PNG
↵↵
IHDR���Ϩ� IDATx���kI�����ꗆ�A��D�ȼ��ؠ�"�ÜY�c��Ys ...
Y2kςo���{d{y'{Ahs���8&���&A↵( n�/������-uےl'��a����U�zv��U�@ �DDDDD1`�&""""��7Q������b��MDDDDo""""�0xŀ������(�DDDDD1`�&""""��7Q������b��MDDDDo""""�0xŀ������(�DDDDD1`�&""""��7Q������b��@��  ��IEND�B`�
```

I tried to convert to base64 string but I can't. I surfed in web for the past two day but I cant' find a solution to this problem.

This is my code snippet:

```
 jQ('<img />',{
     src : "data:image/png;base64," + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(xmlHttpLogoExdanded.responseText))),
     class : "rounded-circle img-photo-profile",
  })
```

Comment: Could the api return a path the the file on the server? Then just make the `src` be the file path.

Comment: The api dont response path to img in the server

Comment: If you build the API, could you not change it to behave as such?

Comment: Are you doing a GET request to the API, or something else (e.g. POST or PUT)?

Comment: I am doing the a GET request